# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4(1-x^2)^5}{(1+x^2)^{10}}dx$

Tags: integration

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4(1-x^2)^5}{(1+x^2)^{10}}dx$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4(1-x^2)^5}{(1+x^2)^{10}}dx$$

Now Put $x=\tan \theta\;,$ Then $dx = \sec^2 \theta d\theta$ and changing limits, We get

$$I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\tan^4 \theta\cdot \left(1-\tan^2 \theta\right)^5}{(1+\tan^2\theta)^{10}}\cdot \sec^2 \theta d\theta = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin^4 \theta\cdot \cos^4 \theta \left(\cos 2 \theta\right)^5 d\theta$$

So $$I = \frac{1}{16}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(\sin 2\theta)^4\cdot (\cos 2 \theta)^4\cdot \cos 2 \theta d\theta$$

Now Put $\sin 2 \theta = t\;,$ Then $2\cos 2 \theta d\theta = dt$ and changing limits, We get

$$I = \frac{1}{64}\int_{0}^{1}t^4(1-t^2)^2 dt$$

Now after expanding , We can integrate it,

My question is can we solve it any other way, If yes then plz explain here

Thanks

Comment: If it's any help, you can try partial fractions; the integrand can be written as

$$-144\, \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{-9}+272\, \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^
{-8}- \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{-3}+32\, \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{-
10}+170\, \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{-6}-61\, \left( {x}^{2}+1
 \right) ^{-5}+12\, \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{-4}-280\, \left( {x}^{2
}+1 \right) ^{-7}$$

Comment: $$\sin^22\theta=u$$ will make things a little easier

Comment: The only other way is partial fraction but it is a pain in the butt.

Comment: The change of variables $t=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: Juan, there was an error in arriving at the last integral in the OP.  The factor outside the integral should be $\frac{1}{32}$, not $\frac{1}{64}$.  Now, I posted a solution that begins there and uses the Beta and Gamma functions to quickly arrive at a solution.  -Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There was a small error in the development in the OP.  The integral $I$ should be $$I=\frac{1}{32}\int_0^1 t^4(1-t^2)^2\,dt$$

We can evaluate the integral of interest in terms of the Beta function, $$B(x,y)=\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt$$and its relationship to the Gamma function, $$B (x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

Note that

$$\begin{align}
I&=\frac{1}{32}\int_0^1 t^4(1-t^2)^2\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{1}{64}\int_0^1 t^{3/2}(1-t)^2 \,dt\,\,\dots\text{enforcing the substitution}\,\,t\to \sqrt{t}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{64}B(5/2,3)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{64}\frac{\Gamma(5/2)\Gamma(3)}{\Gamma(11/2)}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{64}\frac{\left(3\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\right)\,(2!)}{945\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{32}}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{1260}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Juan, there was an error in arriving at the last integral in the OP.  The factor outside the integral should be $\frac{1}{32}$, not $\frac{1}{64}$.  Now, I posted a solution that begins there and uses the Beta and Gamma functions to quickly arrive at a solution.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^1 \frac{x^4(1-x^2)^5}{(1+x^2)^{10}} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1+y)^2} \left(1-\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^5}{\left(1+\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^{10}} \, \sqrt{\frac{1+y}{1-y}} \frac{dy}{(1+y)^2} \tag1 \\
&= -\frac1{32} \int_0^1 y^5 \left(1-y^2\right)^{3/2} \, dy \\
&= \frac1{32} \int_0^1 (1-z)^{5/2} z^{3/2} \, \frac{dz}{2(1-z)^{1/2}} \tag2 \\
&= \frac1{64} \int_0^1 (1-z)^2 z^{3/2} \, dz \\
&= \frac1{64} \int_0^1 \left(z^{3/2} - 2z^{5/2} + z^{7/2}\right) \, dz \\
&= \frac1{64} \left(\frac25 - \frac47 + \frac29\right) = \boxed{\frac1{1260}}
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ : substitute $x=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}}$
- $(2)$ : substitute $y=\sqrt{1-z}$